# How do you stop visual studio 2012 trimming white space on save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

this is really giving me headaches, ever since I installed the last update pack, visual studio[2012] keeps removing white space at the end of each line when I save a file.

it's fine if I'm working on personal projects, but not when working on team projects where code changes are reviewed that gives reviewers hard time for so many changes made turn out to be white spaces

I can't find any settings that turns this off, there're some posts online mentioning about injecting a piece of macro in the IDE to stop this from happening. Seriously? I can't believe Microsoft delivers such a bad feature that there's no way to turn it off...

can anyone here help me out please?

please note it's Visual studio 2012

Comment: Did you use the "Productivity Power Tool"-PlugIn?

Comment: no, but I'm using resharper altho I doubt it has anything to do with the issue, because I tried disabling it the issue remained.

Comment: As far as I know VS can't do this without and extension. Did you have installed other extensions (like CodeMaid)?